# How to Connect Github Repo to Java program and calculate the diff?

Tags: java, git, github

Could someone help me to connect github repo to java program.

I want to get the diff between the latest commit and the latest tagged commit using a java code.

Comment: If you want to do that without the git tools, you could try jgit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Comparing commits GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits) to calculate commit difference.

> For example, this URL uses the shortened seven-character SHA codes to
> compare commits `c3a414e` and `faf7c6f`:
> `https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6f`.

If you use `Accept` header `application/vnd.github.v3.diff` the result would look like

```
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index 50561f3..fcc4164 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
# sandbox

just playing around don’t mind me.
+
+test
....
```

Comment: Hey Alex How should i connect to you , I have some doubts.